# What josei manga features a girl with eyes that change depending on her emotions?

Tags: story-identification, manga

MC is a girl with eyes that change depending on her emotions (it's a trait for all royalty).

She was a slave that was called evil and cursed because of her eyes.

Her real family find her after doing a bust on a noble that is using slaves (because slaves became illegal when the MC's dad became emperor).

I can't remember her hair color. I think it was golden but I don't remember.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could this be *[My Three Tyrant Brothers](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/my-three-tyrant-brothers)*?

[image: Front cover of My Three Tyrant Brothers]

> Given a name from the days of the week. As a slave she was called Wednesday. When she was on the verge of death because of a small revolt, "finally found you." Just overnight, I was told I have three older brothers. Apparently, I am the key to undo the curse on the Askanier Imperial Family.

[This review](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/my-three-tyrant-brothers/reviews), admittedly somewhat critical, mentions the color-changing eyes, and she does have golden hair.

> A story about cursed royalty with mood-ring eyeballs, focused on a girl given Tragic Abused Slave Backstory #12, labeled as 'isekai' only because the author wanted to ride the 'isekai popularity train' when it's really no more than 'sometimes I dream that I lived in another world where there were things called 'planes' and 'cars' and I had a little brother' so... I mean, it counts, but not really.

Found with a search for `manga slave "eyes change color"`

Comment: Thanks so much exactly what I was trying to remember