# Manga/webtoon where a girl's eyes changes color with her emotions

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's the story of these 3 royal princes that have the unique ability to change the color of their eyes due to their emotions.

In the beginning of the story they are a looking for a young girl who is supposed to be their sister. They found her working as a young child slave with a young boy who became her friend; both of them are named after days of the week, one of them is named Wednesday I think. They bring her back home and the boy, he decides he wants to become a knight to protect her. The brothers are very protective of her.

She maybe had blonde hair, but I'm not sure.

Also one of the princes work at the magical tower, a tower that pops out of nowhere.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate, but please don't feel that this is an indication of a bad question. We've just had this one before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[My Three Tyrant Brothers](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/my-three-tyrant-brothers)*

[image: Front cover of My Three Tyrant Brothers]

> All members of the Ascania imperial family are cursed to die at the hands of a loved one, a curse only broken by the birth of a girl into the bloodline. So when a young slave girl with the telltale, color-changing Ascania eyes is discovered, she’s declared Princess Chloe, the little sister of the three princes. She’s excited to finally have a family, but her new brothers seem a bit strange… They’ve always had to be cold and unfeeling for their own protection, but will Chloe’s arrival plant the seed of change in their hearts?

Looking at the reviews, indeed, Chloe was named Wednesday as a slave.

Found with search terms of `manga "three princes" sister slave wednesday`

Comment: If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/251819/what-josei-manga-is-this/251821#251821